# Hide cell with jquery when empty ( no content)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide empty cells with jquery but the code doesn't work

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(jQuery('.tabcontent_01_custom_property_fields').html())
    {
      ( $("th:empty").text().length == 0) .css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Any tips would be great.

Comment: why wouldn't it just be `$("th:empty").css('display', 'none')`? Or `$("th:empty").hide()`

Comment: Why not use CSS directly: `th:empty { display: none; }`?

Comment: You never get luck with any code. There is not luck [while you don't use some randomized algorithms :)]. Computers are stupid. You should to know exactly what are you want they to do.

Comment: I might not explain it well enough. It there is no content between <td> </td> I want the whole <td></td> is removed or not displayed

Answer (score 2):

You already have the `:empty` selector, which is enough. See the working fiddle:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if(jQuery('.table').html())
  {
    ( $("td:empty").css('display', 'none'));
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vym5vk8/1/

**You could even shorten the JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     ( $(".table td:empty").css('display', 'none'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vym5vk8/2/

Comment: I might not explain it well enough. It there is no content between  <td> </td> I want the whole   <td></td> is removed or not displayed

Comment: That's what it does, doesn't it?